# Wordpress uses UTF-8, and the rest of my site uses ISO-8859-1 - character encoding

Tags: php, wordpress

Our client's site uses:
ISO-8859-1 - on its main site
UTF-8 on its "/blog/" directory for it's Wordpress blog, using a template that uses UTF-8 encoding.

This is fine, but on our main site, we also use the Wordpress API functions such as get_the_excerpt() to get the latest news from the blog, and display it on our home page. The problem is that some MS-Word characters seem to be special characters which display fine on the blog, but display like this on our home page:

Key Brand â€“ test

I tried changing my meta character encoding to UTF-8, but it didn't help. Instead, this PHP code works:

htmlentities($except_text, 1, "UTF-8", 0)

Even though I encode it from UTF-8, it works fine on my ISO-8859-1 template. I'm not too experienced on the character-encoding side of things, and I'll go ahead with the above fix, but I just want to know if anyone can explain why the above works and why changing my character encoding didn't work? The character itself is valid (e.g. the - hyphen in Word and the 'quotes' generated in Word).

[UPDATE] Actually, it doesn't work fine. The above also goes ahead and converts my "read more" link to  a readable < a href > tag - i.e. the HTML is actually converted :( Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks,
Rishi

Comment: Did you try to change character encoding with `header()` php function also? Your server may encode pages as iso-8859-1 and changing only meta will not always help. By the way, if your site is in english and uses only basic characters than you could easily made it UTF-8.

Comment: htmlentities doesn't convert between character sets. You use mb_convert_encoding() for that.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesnt work, I just tried : a) header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  --- this does not fix the problem and doesn't seem to change anything on the problematic character. b) For mb_convert_encoding, see my comment below.

Comment: Than you may use `iconv` for converting characters http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php (You need to set //TRANSLIT or //IGNORE because utf-8 includes much more characters than iso-8859-1).

Answer (score 1):

htmlentities will convert non-ASCII characters to HTML entities - `&rsquo;` etc., which will then be interpreted correctly regardless of whether the client is expecting latin1 or utf8.

`mb_convert_encoding($excerpt_text, "ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8")` is probably what you need to do the conversion. If the WP blog contains non-latin1 characters, you're SOL of course.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried this: print(mb_convert_encoding($excerpt_text, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1")); --- and unfortunately it did not work. For example, a german Euro symbol is Zurück - which comes out as ZurÃ¼ck in my code. After trying mb_convert_encoding, it comes out as ZurÃƒÂ¼ck

Comment: Sorry, I think I got the arguments to mb_convert_encoding the wrong way round. Try reversing them (I'll edit the answer)

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much :) I wonder why changing my charset using header didn't work though. Maybe I should change the meta tag and force the header and try once more and will update this ticket, but mb_convert_encoding does work so that's great!

Comment: if your charset in the response header and the meta tag disagree, then browsers may just throw their hands in the air, snort deprecatingly and then guess. And may be more likely to guess iso-8859-1 (which won't produce decoding errors) or to trust the meta tag (which content authors may have more control over).