# Wordpress UTF-8 encoding issue. Help implementing possible solution?

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress blog shows Â characters in place of special characters/symbols such as £.

The problem occurs upon saving the post to the database, and viewing it on the live page. Viewing it on the edit page does not show Â.

I've been through many tutorials and suggestions (fresh WP install, converting database to UTF-8, making sure all pages are UTF-8 etc) and nothing has worked - but I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8927808/837780) answer on Stackoverflow that may help.

My problem is I can't figure out where to implement the code in Wordpress. I'm using the Genesis framework with a theme called Agency.

I would comment on that post to find the answer, but I'm a new user and don't have enough reputation to do so.

The code I need to use is:

```
mb_convert_encoding($excerpt_text, "UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1")
```

But I can't find where the post content is even generated or printed on the page, in order to add this code.

Comment: I know this isn't helpful for actually applying the function since you don't know where to put it, but you don't need to use the full `mb_convert_encoding()` function for those two specific encodings. They are predefined with `utf8_encode`. This will be faster as it is not using the mbstring library. So in your case: `$excerpt_text = utf8_encode($excerpt_text);` will do the job (once you know where to put it).

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on wordpress forum

http://wilfing.se/forum/utf8.png

Try following steps in the image

OR

Try adding this in your `<head>`

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Is your database charset set in UTF-8?
2. Add utf-8 meta charset
3. In your wp-config.php, make sure that the DB_CHARSET config is set to utf8:

   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
4. Make sure all the files of your project are in UTF-8 format.

If it's still not working, you can try to detect the encoding and try to re-encode as utf-8 before displaying your text or reset DB_CHARSET and your database charset at the same value as your database was really set.

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mb-convert-encoding.php